# Android Development

Tags: android

Is it possible for a program to mimic the Android Homepage?  Can widgets, contacts, and canvases all interact at the appropriate FPS?  Is it possible for an app to make calls and IMs?  Or are the ISOs used to make the original too different from Java to mimic correctly?

Comment: Too many questions in one question. What research have you done? Try to focus your question and you'll get better results.

Answer (score 0):

To a large extent yes . For a start have a look at the home app sample provided by google . http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html .

Once you get your home app working perfectly you can add modules which practically do everything , but a better design strategy is to split the modules which do different work , so you calling module can be a different app.

I dont think there should be a fps issue if you have good code :) .